# Plesk Parallels can't send email to account with external MX records

Tags: sendmail, phpmailer, plesk, qmail, mail-form

My domain @thisdomain.com is sat on my VPS. This VPS is the NameServer and provides the DNS for @thisdomain.com. The mail server for @thisdomain.com is hosted with an external webmail service provided by GoDaddy.

Unfortunately my mail forms on my website on the VPS (thisdomain.com) can not be set to send to any emails @thisdomain.com because it doesn't seem to look at the MX records on the DNS which point to the web server. Instead it looks locally for the account on the VPS (which clearly doesn't exist)

This is a copy of the bounce back I get, does anybody have any thoughts?

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at ip-100-255-30-47.ip.secureserver.net.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<sales@thisdomain.com>:
This address no longer accepts mail.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.
```

there is more of it, however I think this is the relevant part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following article on Parallels website for this issue

http://kb.parallels.com/en/116927

**Resolution**

Disable the mail service for the domain.tld subscription:

```
Go to Subscriptions > domain.tld > Mail > Change Settings.
Uncheck Activate mail service on domain and click OK.
```

You can also disable the mail service on the subscription using the command-line utility mail:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/mail --off domain.tld
```

To disable the mail service for every subscription on the server, use the following command:

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa -Nse"select name from domains where parentDomainId=0"|while read i; do /usr/local/psa/bin/mail --off $i && echo "Mail service for $i subscription has been disabled" ;done
```

I wish I knew how to do this for every subscription through phpMyAdmin my running a mySQL query...

Comment: You can't do it through phpMyAdmin. Just run this last command in the shell.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and marking answers (checking the mark below the votes) to the answers of the questions you found helpful. It helps everyone earn those meaningless internet points. :)